# Use array value while declaring an array in PHP

Tags: php

I was wondering...is it possible to use a value from an array which is currently being declared? Something like:

```
$a = array(
    'foo' => 'value',
    'bar' => $a['foo']
);
```

This is only a simple example. It would be pretty useful doing this, since it frees you from doing extra manipulation after the array declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't, but you can do something like :

```
$a = array(
    'foo' => ($val = 'value'),
    'bar' => $val
);
```

Comment: An interesting approach. Although you use an extra variable, you at least don't have to manipulate the array after. Seems to be the best approach possible in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

No. `$a['foo']` will only be available after the assignment completes entirely.